# open : Resource busy when trying to communicate to arduino

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, arduino, serial-port

I have a very simple question but for some reason I can't find any answer. I'm a total beginner with arduino and c++. I just want to be able to send an angle from xcode to a servo motor. I'm on macos 10.9.5.

So my arduino is connected to the serial port "/dev/cu.usbmodem1411". My c++ code connects to this port and send a number. Then my arduino should receive it and control the servo. It's pretty simple but apparently my c++ code can't access the serial port when my arduino is connected. How am I supposed to make them communicate ?

If I run my c++ code first, I get a timeout error on arduino.

Here is my arduino code :

```
#include <AFMotor.h>
#include <Servo.h> 

Servo servo1;

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   servo1.attach(9);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()>0){
     int x;
     x = Serial.read()
     servo1.write(x);
     }
```

And my c++ code :

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned int angle;
    fstream arduino;
    arduino.open("/dev/cu.usbmodem1411");        
    if(arduino.is_open())
    {
        do
        {
            cout<<"\n\nangle ?";
            cin>>angle;
            arduino<<angle;

        }while(angle <= 360);
        arduino.close();

    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"error";
    }
}
```

I tried another c++ code using the boost library and received the error "open: Resource busy". I have no problem if I try to connect to another port like "/dev/tty.usbmodem1411" but it's not proposed in the arduino tool menu.

My problem is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515210/xcode-c-serial-port-with-arduino) that didn't have a convincing solution.